# Why my Kafka connect sink cluster only has one worker processing messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I've recently setup a local Kafka on my computer for testing and development purposes:

- 3 brokers
- One input topic
- Kafka connect sink between the topic and elastic search

I managed to configure it in standalone mode, so everything is localhost, and the Kafka connect was started using `./connect-standalone.sh` script.

What I'm trying to do now is to run my connectors in distributed mode, so the Kafka messages can be separated into both workers.
I've started the two workers (still everything on the same machine), but when I send message to my Kafka topic, only one worker (the last started) is processing messages.

So my question is: **Why only one worker is processing Kafka messages instead of both** ?

When I kill one of the worker, the other one takes the message flow back, so I think the cluster is well setup.

**What I think:**

- I don't put Keys inside my Kafka messages, can it be related to this ?
- I'm running everything in localhost, does distributed mode can work this way ? (I've correctly configure specific unique field such as `ret.port`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved:**

From Kafka documentation:

> The division of work between tasks is shown by the partitions that each task is assigned

If you don't use partition (push all messages in same partition), workers won't be able to divide messages.
You don't need to use message keys, you can just push your messages to different partition in a cyclic way.

See: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/concepts.html#distributed-workers